# Display WooCommerce Payment Gateway Admin Settings

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment

I've developed a custom payment gateway for WooCommerce but I can't get the admin settings to display.

The plugin is broken into three files, main.php, class.php and settings.php.

The gateway is displaying on my front end and is fully functional, however, since the settings are not shown on the backend everything is hard coded.
[This is how I'm calling settings.php in class.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E1cqh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The admin options function responsible for displaying settings was missing from my code.

```
`function admin_options() {
 ?>
 <h2><?php _e('Settings Tab','woocommerce'); ?></h2>
 <table class="form-table">
 <?php $this->generate_settings_html(); ?>
 </table> <?php
 }`
```